# How to add padding to the default arrow in a select dropdown list?

Tags: html-select

I'm trying to follow a design of a select dropdown-list where:

- Padding: 0 10px 0 10px

However, the arrow is not being adjusted at all. It keeps sticking to the right end. Please see attached screenshot for reference.[Front End Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lvpi.png)

[You can also view my codes here](https://liveweave.com/sjuIyU)

Is there a way to target the specific arrow and apply paddings to it? (Aiming to keep the same padding applied to the input text for both sides)

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, please share your code so I can help you

Comment: @Nikasmusicandgaming Hi! I have added respective links above, thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Add the code so we can tweak it for you wherever necessary

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For those who have the same question, I found a work around how to style the default select "arrow" which is by replacing it with generated content.

Step 1: Hiding the default arrow

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Step 2: Create extra wrapper around select, because ::before/::after doesn't work this way.

```
<div class="select-wrapper"><select id="select" name="select">
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Cherry</option>
  <option>Lemon</option>
</select></div>
```

Step 3: Apply generated content

```
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.select-wrapper::after {
  content: "▼";
  font-size: 1rem;
  top: 6px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Codes above originated from
[Advanced form styling | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling#Dealing_with_the_select_nightmare)

Comment: remember to add pointer-events: none; to the select to allow click on select at that area.

Comment: @funky-nd nice comment! Worked indeed.

Comment: Simple and elegant! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: I feel like this is the "correct" method but the top answer is the "best" method.

Answer (score 51):

I used border-right property and it worked.

```
select {
  border-right: 16px solid transparent
}
```

The problem with wrapper element and ":after" is that, it does not toggle the "select" dropdown when you click on the arrow icon.

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/asaad7/r8sx9m7e/

Comment: Good suggestion! The only downside is that this breaks any existing border around your `<select>` element. However, I got around that by simply wrapping my `<select>` in a `<div>`, and moving my styled border there instead!

Comment: I don't understand why this solution has so many upvotes, making the border transparent makes this looks ugly and is just unusable.

Comment: I think is amazing suggestion but didn't work in my case because I have border color and right side looking more wider

Answer (score 12):

Solution without wrapper div

```
<select id="birthDate.dateYear" name="birthDate.dateYear" >
         <option value="">Year</option>
         
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
         
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
         
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
         
    </select>
```

CSS

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
-moz-appearance: none !important;
background-color: #fafafa;
height: 45px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAMAAACtdX32AAAAdVBMVEUAAAD///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhMdQaAAAAJ3RSTlMAAAECAwQGBwsOFBwkJTg5RUZ4eYCHkJefpaytrsXGy8zW3+Do8vNn0bsyAAAAYElEQVR42tXROwJDQAAA0Ymw1p9kiT+L5P5HVEi3qJn2lcPjtIuzUIJ/rhIGy762N3XaThqMN1ZPALsZPEzG1x8LrFL77DHBnEMxBewz0fJ6LyFHTPL7xhwzWYrJ9z22AqmQBV757MHfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
background-position: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 0.5rem;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aj4orwue/10/

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we can add padding for the default arrow in `<select>` tag. But this is a simple workaround I found.

- Hide the default arrow
- Add an arrow as a background image to select, and position it however you want

**Hiding the arrow:**

```
/* Removing the default arrow */
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

**Adding custom arrow:**

```
/* Custom arrow */
select {
  background-image: url("/images/icons/caret-down-light.svg");
  background-size: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 8px) center;
}
```

The result would be something like this:
[image: Dropdown showing the result]

The caret down image I took, is from Google Icons, you can find it [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Symbols%20Outlined%3Aexpand_more%3AFILL%400%3Bwght%40100%3BGRAD%400%3Bopsz%4048)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answer you'd better add z-index to elements to place pseudo-element ::after "behind" the original select. Else nothing happends when user clicks the arrow.

```
select {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
}

.select-wrapper::after {
    z-index: 0;
}
```