# How to add padding to the arrow present in html select?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I wanted to add padding to the right side of the arrow present in the HTML select
[how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX0ok.png).

I do not want to change the looks of the arrow. Just want a padding to the right side.

This is the html code -

```
<div class="blood-type">
<select class="rectangle">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select One</option>
    <option *ngFor="let bg of bgList" [value]="bg.id">{{bg.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have tried adding padding to the rectangle class as well as the blood-type class but both doesn't work.

```
.blood-type{
    padding-right: 0.5rem; 
}
```

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120873/how-to-add-padding-to-the-default-arrow-in-a-select-dropdown-list) but the text arrow does not looks good. I can also use the arrow_drop_down icon if it is possible to use icon.

Comment: Please provide code examples, what did you try, what is the error. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I agree with @kmp. Please add code example so we can asses what the problem is.

Comment: You should wrap select with div, and customize the div but not select

Comment: @YevheniiShlapak Yup I tried that, does not work.

Comment: @AyushPatwari you also have to add the icon of arrow to `.blood-type::after` and put it where ever you want.

Comment: If the arrow is custom made, please provide CSS code as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could help:

**CSS:**

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
}
.blood-type {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.blood-type::after {
    content: "▼";
    font-size: 1rem;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.rectangle {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blood-type">
    <select class="rectangle">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select One</option>
        <option *ngFor="let bg of bgList" [value]="bg.id">{{bg.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have already tried this (mentioned in the question). The drop down looks weird to me. I can use [this icon](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Aarrow_drop_down%3A) instead of normal text icon ("▼") if it is possible to do so.

Comment: @AyushPatwari, sure, you will only need to change the 'content' tag inside `.blood-type::after`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the spacing between the dropdown arrow and the border, you can't - it's a built-in browser control and may look completely different in different browsers. The only option is to write your own element styling from scratch, which is almost certainly not worth the trouble. Generally, try not to get too hung up on controlling every aspect of your user's experience - there's a lot to be said for consistency in controls across different websites!

Comment: In reality a custom arrow isn't a big deal. It takes a bit of coding but if it makes your design more readable, more fluid, it's certainly worth it

Comment: I think I am willing to go the extra mile. Can you guys provide any good resources?

Comment: There's loads of tutorials out there - [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp) have one, for example.