# Add padding right to the Dropdown input in Html with CSS

Tags: css

So I have a provblem with the dropdown that shows this arrow on the right aligned to the end, and I can't find a way to fix it.

[image]

Here is the scss:

```
.select_box {
    width: 120%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: var(--header-bg);
    border: 1px solid var(--border);
    font-family: "Space Grotesk";
    transition: var(--animate);
    border-radius: 0.65em;
    color: var(--color-inactive);
    outline: none;

    &:hover {
        background: var(--hover-color);
        border: var(--icon) 1px solid;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need your html to can help you.

Comment: just a normal select nothing else, the arrow comes from the browser, but I don't know how to give padding to it: <select><option>a</option></select>

Comment: I think this is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120873/how-to-add-padding-to-the-default-arrow-in-a-select-dropdown-list